# i18n translation key/value pairs

Tags: internationalization

How do you recommend to name the translation keys ?

Should I use the actual text (that needs to be translated) as the translation key ?
e.g.

```
Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.=But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
```

Or should I use keys like

```
content_lorem_ipsum_par_1=But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when, due to context and grammatical differences, a same piece of text in your base language has to be translated differently in two different places. This might be a problem if you use the former, so I advise to use the latter approach.

Comment: Yes, also make sure you do not concatenate to form sentences.